# Marionette: Check if a layout has an instance of another object

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, marionette

I'm looking for a way to remove the need to rerender a layout if an instance of it is already in use. Below the index makes a new PreactivationLayout and then binds it to the main region of the app object. Then if you were to visit page2 I would like to check if the PreactivationLayout is in use; if so just swap out the regions, if not create a new instance and add it to the app object.

```
class IndexController extends Marionette.Controller
    initialize: (options)->
        @app = options.app

    index: ->

        layout = new PreactivationLayout()

        @app.main.show layout
        layout.main.show new IndexView()

    page2:  ->

        // Is the current layout an instace of the Preactivation class?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this, this will check to see if the view currently inside of the region has the same constructor.

```
if(!layout.main.currentView || layout.main.currentView.constructor !== PreactivationLayout){
     layout.main.show(new PreactivationLayout());
}
```

or as Tan Nguyen suggested in the comments,

```
if(!layout.main.currentView || !(layout.main.currentView instanceof PreactivationLayout)){
     layout.main.show(new PreactivationLayout());
}
```

Comment: How about `layout.main.currentView instanceof PreactivationLayout`? Same thing, am I right?

Comment: @TanNguyen yes, same result. I actually like your syntax better, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Sweet, it makes the code a little bit shorter for lazy people like myself